# SQLAlchemy - how to make column unique per ForeignKey relationship?

Tags: sqlalchemy

In the `Todo` model below there is a unique constraint put on `text` column.

How can I narrow this constraint to validate uniqueness per "foreign-keyed" user only, not per all users as it is now?

I use SQLite.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from database import Base

class Todo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'todos'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    text = Column(String, unique=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="todos")

class User(Base):
    __tablename__  = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    todos = relationship("Todo", back_populates="user")
```

Comment: what database do you use?

Comment: I use SQLite...

Comment: just replace `postgresql_where` with `sqlite_where` in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use postgresql, you can use the [Partial Index](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#partial-indexes) to implement this:

```
class Todo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'todos'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    text = Column(String)  # ! removed the unique from here
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="todos")

    # ! added unique index with 
    __table_args__ = (
        Index(
            "todo_text_uc",
            "text",
            unique=True,
            postgresql_where=(user_id != None),
            # postgresql_where=(~user_id.is_(None)),  # equivalent to the row above, but no linting warnings
        ),
    )
```

> For `sqlite` just replace `postgresql_where` with `sqlite_where`.